# In Sql Server 2008,2012 can temp tables have full text indexes?

Tags: sql-server

In Sql Server 2008,2012 can temp tables have full text indexes?

When I run the command

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON #temp (SearchTerms) KEY INDEX [ix_clustered] ON FTC;
```

I get

```
Invalid object name '#temp'
```

Should this work? MSDN technet doesn't list it as a limitation.

Comment: Full text indexes are populated asynchronously.  Your table doesn't sound very temporary if you want to create it, then wait a while for the index to be created, then start using the index.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214429%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), no it is not possible:

> A full-text index must be defined on a base table; it cannot be
>   defined on a view, system table, or temporary table.

This should be clarified to point out that since the version that documentation was written for, indexed views were added to SQL Server, and [documentation there states that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx):

> one full-text index is allowed per table or indexed view