# Creating Full Text index on temporary table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I create a full text index on a temporary table #Table in a query? I got Invalid name object #Table.
Is creating full text index possible in sql server?

Comment: Similar [In Sql Server 2008,2012 can temp tables have full text indexes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059917/in-sql-server-2008-2012-can-temp-tables-have-full-text-indexes)

Answer (score 4):

According to [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214429%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), no it is not possible:

> A full-text index must be defined on a base table; it cannot be
>   defined on a view, system table, or temporary table.

This should be clarified to point out that since the version that documentation was written for, indexed views were added to SQL Server, and [documentation there states that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx):

> one full-text index is allowed per table or indexed view